# AdSense on Android

Tags: android, admob, ads, adsense

Because AdMob get shutdown, I want to setup AdSense for my app.

I read through the guides, https://developers.google.com/adsense-for-mobile-apps/docs/?hl=de#afma-networks and android specific https://developers.google.com/adsense-for-mobile-apps/docs/android/?hl=de.

Where can I get the AdSense SDK (GoogleAdView.jar)?

Comment: Where do you see that AdMob is shutting down? I know they got rid of their mobile web stuff, but I'm not aware of anything like that for the app side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the admob page, it's mobile webpage ads that are being discontinued, not apps ads

> We are simplifying our suite of products by transitioning AdMob mobile
>   web publishers to Google AdSense. Starting May 1, 2012 support for
>   mobile web sites on AdMob will be discontinued and you must have a
>   Google AdSense account to monetize mobile web sites.

Answer (score 0):

AdSense for Android is still in beta. See [this forum thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/AdSense/thread?tid=0d0fe53ca006d699). Once you sign up and are given access, you can download the SDK.

Please note that AdMob is still up and running. It's now owned by Google.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you need to wait for the wider public release or hope to get involved in their AdSense for Android beta. Brute forcing ads to be displayed within your app is otherwise against the T&Cs and is likely to get you permanently terminated from the AdSense programme.